# Install spring-boot-starter-parent and upload to nexus

Tags: spring-boot

I would like to install the spring-boot-starter-parent jar and upload it to my private nexus 3 repo. Then I hope to configure my project pom file to retrieve the dependency from there. How can i download spring-boot-starter-parent jar?

My intention is to set up this nexus repo so that future projects will pull depencies from this nexus repo (where this environment is not connected to the internet)

Comment: `spring-boot-starter-parent` is only a pom file and doesn't have a jar artifact associated with it.

Comment: How can i upload the contents to nexus given a pom file? I am new to this thanks

Answer (score 0):

No need to upload in your nexus. You can configure proxy-repository:

**`A repository that proxies everything you download from Maven Central. Next time you download the same dependency, it will be cached in your Nexus.`**

Look at [this for details](https://blog.sonatype.com/using-nexus-3-as-your-repository-part-1-maven-artifacts)

Need to do following configuration:

```
– create a private (hosted) repository for our snapshots
– create a private (hosted) repository for our releases
– create a proxy repository pointing to Maven Central
– create a group repository to provide all of these repos under a single URL
```

Another procedure:

If you want to upload list of jar then write gradle task to upload nexus repository. [here](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-upload-a-list-of-jars-into-nexus-or-artifac) you get details.

Comment: I need to upload as I hope to set this nexus in an air gap environment with no internet access. so future spring boot projects will pull maven depenencies from this nexus

Comment: Is there a way to do so with maven?

Comment: I have the same problem that @NinjaDude. I have added the proxies to Nexus, and to the maven public group. I don't know if I have to modify the settings.xml file as well. Any help?